# R lme4 model: calculating effect size between continuous predictor's max-min value

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, lme4

I'm struggling to calculate an effect size between a continuous predictor's max-min value while using an R lme4 multilevel model.

**Simulated data:** predictor "x" ranges from 1 to 3

```
library(tidyverse)
n = 100
a = tibble(y = rep(c("pos", "neg", "neg", "neg"), length.out = n), x = rep(3, length.out = n), group = rep(letters[1:7], length.out = n))
b = tibble(y = rep(c("pos", "pos", "neg", "neg"), length.out = n), x = rep(2, length.out = n), group = rep(letters[1:7], length.out = n))
c = tibble(y = rep(c("pos", "pos", "pos", "neg"), length.out = n), x = rep(1, length.out = n), group = rep(letters[1:7], length.out = n))
d = rbind(a, b)
df = rbind(d, c)
df = df %>% mutate(y = as.factor(y))
df
```

[image]

**Model**

```
library("lme4")
m = glmer(
  y ~ x + (x | group), 
  data = df, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

**Output**

```
ggpredict(m, "x")
```

.

```
# Predicted probabilities of y

x | Predicted |       95% CI
----------------------------
1 |      0.75 | [0.67, 0.82]
2 |      0.50 | [0.44, 0.56]
3 |      0.25 | [0.18, 0.33]

Adjusted for:
* group = 0 (population-level)
```

**I'm failing to calculate the effect size between the predictor's "x" max (3) and min (1) value**

My best try

```
library("emmeans")
emmeans(m, "x", trans = "logit", type = "response", at = list(x = c(1, 3)))
```

```
 x response     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1     0.75 0.0387 Inf     0.667     0.818
 3     0.25 0.0387 Inf     0.182     0.333

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale
```

**How can I calculate the effect size with CIs between the predictor's "x" max (3) and min (1) value?** The effect size should be in probability scale.

Comment: perhaps `pairs(emmeans(...))`?

Comment: seems not to give an effect size...

Comment: Then I am stumped. Usually people who ask for effect sizes want some standardized, unit-less measure. but you said you wanted it on a probability scale. What I suggested does that. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Why so? In bayesian regression, calculating such effect sizes in probability scale (also logit link model) is really easy. Maybe frequentist analogy can only give probabilities at different continuous predictor's levels (my example above)? It is not possible to calculate effect size with CIs between the predictor's max and min value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer, though I'm still not sure what the question is. I am going to assume that what is wanted is the difference between the two probabilities.

There are a lot of moving parts in the `emmeans` call shown, so I will proceed in smaller steps. First, let's get estimates of the probabilities in question:

```r
> library(emmeans)
> EMM = emmeans(m, "x", at = list(x = c(1, 3)), type = "response")
> EMM
 x prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1 0.75 0.0387 Inf     0.667     0.818
 3 0.25 0.0387 Inf     0.182     0.333

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale
```

The quickest way to obtain a pairwise comparison is via

```r
> pairs(EMM)
 contrast odds.ratio   SE  df null z.ratio p.value
 1 / 3             9 2.94 Inf    1   6.728  <.0001

Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

As stated in the annotations (and also in the documentation, e.g. the [vignette on comparisons](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#logs), when a log or logit transformation is in place, the comparison is shown as a ratio. This happens because the tests are performed on the link (logit) scale, and the difference between logs is the log of a ratio.

If we want the difference between probabilities, it is necessary to create a new object where the primary quantities being estimated are the probabilities, rather than their logits. In **emmeans**, this may be done via the `regrid()` function:

```r
> EMMP = regrid(EMM, transform = "response")
> EMMP
 x prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1 0.75 0.0387 Inf     0.674     0.826
 3 0.25 0.0387 Inf     0.174     0.326

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

This output looks a lot like the summary of `EMM`; however, all memory of the logit transformation has been erased, thus the confidence intervals are different because they are calculated directly from the SEs of the `prob` estimates. For more information, see the [vignette on transformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#regrid).
So now if we compare these, we get the difference of the probabilities:

```r
> confint(pairs(EMMP))
 contrast estimate     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1 - 3         0.5 0.0612 Inf      0.38      0.62

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

(*Note:* I wrapped this in `confint()` so that we woul;d obtain a confidence interval, rather than the default summary of the *t* ratio and *P* value.)

This could be accomplished in one line of code as follows:

```r
confint(pairs(emmeans(m, "x", transform = "response", at = list(x = c(1, 3)))))
```

The `transform` argument requests that the reference grid be immediately passed to `regrid()`. Note that the correct argument here is `transform = "response"`, rather than `transform = "logit"` (that is, specify what you want to end with, not what you started with). The latter undoes, then redoes, the logit transformation, putting you back where you started.

The **emmeans** package provides a lot of options, and I really do recommend reading the vignettes.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!